Reconnecting a water heater from three-phase to single-phase (220V)
I switched from three-phase to single-phase system. Since the water heater was connected using 3 phases I need to change the connection to use it (It seems it could be done by changing the red/blue wires, and/or the little "grays wires" attached to the base of the screw visible on the picture below ― it's possible according to the schematics).
Measure of the heating resistor part:
(I draw a black line between the numbers to show that there is 0Ω) There is 0Ω between 2 and everything else. I tested both using the continuity bip, and ohmmeter. I find it very strange that these resistors connections are touching the casing.

(I also don't understand how it is possible that there is a continuity between pin 2 and 1 and between pin 2 and 3 but no continuity between pin 1 and 3)
The numbers on the schematic doesn't seem to fit with the installation
I found several schematics (on the plastic cover that protects the parts shown on the picture). Only the one below seems to fit because the others (cf the picture at the end) use either 3 phases, or are either incomplete, or use only 1 heating resistor. (I don't mind if the heater is slower ―still much better than cold shower― I just had to pick one schematic, maybe it's not the right one)


this schematic mention #5 but there is nothing on it (cf. picture below)
they put the live on #2 but it's the earth-grounded (attached to the metal case)
why is the connection between #2→#3 white/empty, while #5→#3 and 3→4 are black?
why is there a light between 2 and 4?

Based on those issue should I rewire like this:

My first try (to use only 1 resistor) :
After switching to single-phase, I needed to power the heater at least to power the small anti-corrosion device inside (or to recharge the small battery that takes over to power the anti-corrosion during a power outage ― because it died after 48 hours).
● (Rewiring of the heating resistor) Assuming the water heater is using three heating resistors, to limit problems, I attempted to power only one resistor. Therefore, I disconnected two red wires (refer to the pictures). I kept only one red wire connected to pin 2 of the resistor and the two blue wires on pin 1 (assuming that the blue wires are neutral).
● (Rewiring of the power/entry) Since the heater was originally powered by three wires connected to pins A, B, and C of the heater, I had to determine which one should be connected to the live and neutral. I tried every combination. Only two combinations turn on the heater led: 1(A=live and B=neutral), and 2(A=neutral and B=live). Initially, I thought only the first combination was working because the second one produced a high-frequency humming or buzzing noise. However, I later discovered that this was unrelated, as it also occurred sometimes with the first combination when I restarted the power. In such cases, the noise stopped when I restarted the power again.
The current rewiring look like this https://imgur.com/xvR9V5o
Result:
The system charges the battery (so it probably also runs its anti-oxidation feature), which is great as it provides me with some time to find a solution. However, it does not heat the water ― there is no voltage between the (only remaining) red and the blue wires of the resistors.
These Pictures show how it was connected with the tree-phases:


All schematics

Side question [already answered: thanks!]:
why the water heater is power by 3 and not 4 wires (3 phase + 1 neutral)?
Side note:
The manufacturer can't help because the label containing the model number and other specs has been destroyed.

Where in the world (approimately, not your street address) is this 220V 3-phase/single phase - local standard methods vary somewhat.

What's the 2-4 resistance? Also 120Ω?

Curious why you made this switch?

Code says you should not be guessing, freestyling, or asking the Internet. You need to google the instructions for that model of water heater, and follow those instructions re: whether and how you connect it to a supply.

@jay613 I dont need it and it's way more expensive where I live (by the way I added a schematic)

@Ecnerwal   yes 2-4 is also 120Ω (sorry, my drawing was confusing, I edited it) (I forgot to add the schematics I found, please look at my question)

@Ecnerwal  it's in France (sorry I missed this one)

I'm sure French code says something to the effect of respecter les instructions.

You also removed all the pictures (though you still reference a schematic). Pictures help us help you.

3 phases with no neutral is a Delta configuration rather than a Wye configuration of 3-phase.
Given that 3-phase supply to houses and 220V supply period (240 is nominal in 120V areas) is unusual in the area where 120V to neutral is common, the other possibility is that the heater was connected to two phases and neutral of a higher-voltage (~400V) phase-to-phase Wye.
However, the circuit board indicates 400V 3~ (presumably meaning phase) at 50 Hz, and does not have any standard "neutral" color coming into it, so it may be the case that you need a whole new water heater to use 220-230V single phase, or else you will have very slow water heating (if the heater does not have circuitry that fails to work on much lower voltage than intended. Heating elements just lose power drastically. Other things may not work at all.)
Your resistance measurements may mean the heater can be used at two different voltages. Best to contact the manufacturer to find out how that should be done properly.

Jeez, good eye reading the circuit board!    +1 for contact manufacturer, (or at least RTFM) and probably replace the thing.

Thanks for your answer! The manufacturer can't help me (I edited my question) I also forgot to add the schematics I found. These schematics seem to say that there is a way to convert it (unfortunately I don't understand the resistor part on it, and why there are so many options, and the point of drawing only part of it). By the way I don't mind having a slow heater, it's better than nothing (I can't afford a new one)

Perhaps you could get more info from the mfr if you sent photos of the unit along with the schematics.  Or take the docs to a local plumbing supply house.

To answer the optional question: you have three heating elements, one per phase, each of which is a 60 ohm resistance between the hot and point 1 in your diagram.  If this was connected to a three-phase supply with neutral included, there would be very little current on the neutral anyway since the three resistances are equal.

Thanks for your help! (By the way I added some schematics I found on the plastic cover, on my question)
